# Adding the scrollview created by photoscroller to a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I'm trying to modify Apple's [PhotoScroller example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html) to make the scrollview that is created into a subview instead of it being a view that takes up the entire screen. Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

```
- (void)loadView 
{    
    // Step 1: make the outer paging scroll view
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];
    pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
    pagingScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    pagingScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    pagingScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    pagingScrollView.contentSize = [self contentSizeForPagingScrollView];
    pagingScrollView.delegate = self;

    // When I do this it fails
    [self.view addSubview:pagingScrollView];

    // Step 2: prepare to tile content
    recycledPages = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    visiblePages  = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    [self tilePages];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the frame of the scrollview to be positioned and sized how you want:

This is the line in the view controller that sets it up in the example

```
pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:pagingScrollViewFrame];
```

As an example here is a sample frame with some hardcoded values:

```
CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectMake(100,100,100,100);
pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
```

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to change the size and position, but when I try to add it to a subview (changing self.view = pagingScrollView to [self.view addSubview:pagingScrollView]) it crashes due to BAD ACCESS.

Comment: You should be able to add it as a subview without a problem. Where are you calling this code from? You may want to post more code to help narrow down the source of the problem. You may also want to debug through the code to see which item isn't getting instantiated (resulting in the bad access).

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my post with the code block I changed. As a note, I have modified frameForPagingScrollView to give me a custom frame (instead of hardcoding with a CGRectMake)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that I was able to add the scrollView as a subview by changing the method from loadView to viewDidLoad.

I have no clue why that works, but it does. I'd love to know why that's the case however...